# How to select a table column with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors

I want to select a table column and all I know is the header text of the column. (th.innerText)

I tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
ownerIndex = $('th:contains("Owner")').index();
$('table tr td:nth-child(ownerIndex)')
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Ok. I found a solution:

```
$('table tr td:nth-child('+ownerIndex+')')
```

Comment: This works if every cell has colspan=1, but breaks if cells have different column spans.

Comment: Thanks, I have added to your idea in order to set columns widths for "table-layout:fixed" style. In this case I select children from colgroup eg. $('#plGrid colgroup col:nth-child(0)').css('width', '150px'); $('#plGrid colgroup col:nth-child(1)').css('width', '250px');

Comment: make that nth-child(1); nth-child(2)

Answer (score 28):

In the example above ownerIndex needs to be incremented by 1 to match the indexing of nth-child, which starts at 1 rather than 0.

Here's my take:
http://jsfiddle.net/2xU8t/

```
/* Set all the cells in columns with THEHEADING in the heading to red */

// Find the heading with the text THEHEADING
columnTh = $("table th:contains('THEHEADING')");

// Get the index & increment by 1 to match nth-child indexing
columnIndex = columnTh.index() + 1; 

// Set all the elements with that index in a tr red
$('table tr td:nth-child(' + columnIndex + ')').css("color", "#F00");

// Set the heading red too!
columnTh.css("color", "#F00");
```

Comment: This is the only answer that's actually correct. The others, including the one with the most votes, miss the fact that `.index()` will return a zero-based index (i.e. the first column's index is 0), whereas `:nth-child` takes an argument which is 1-based (i.e. the first column will be `:nth-child(1)`.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work using the back tick as opposed to a single quote:

```
$(`table tr td:nth-child(${ownerIndex})`)
```

Answer (score 0):

the examples above do not work me, because my cell don't have same cosplan, and i found this solution:

```
 $("table tr>td:nth-child(${ownerIndex})");
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
$("table tbody tr td:eq(4)")
```

on mine to only get one result..

Oddly enough, find TRs first, then find td:eq(col) worked correctly..

```
$("table tbody tr").find("td:eq(4)")
```

For colspan issues, I recommend adding a class to handle it correctly..

```
<td class="CALC" colspan=2>

$("table .CALC")
```