# jQuery set alternate color for multiple set of columns

Tags: jquery

We can use jQuery to set the alternate color of table rows:

```
$("tr:odd").css("background-color", "white");
$("tr:even").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Is it possible to use this pattern for the first set of columns, and another color combination(s) for the second set, or more sets of columns?

Comment: what about `:nth-child(N)`?

Comment: Why not use class to separate the sets of columns. Also check out this thread, hope it will help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375625/jquery-select-table-column

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks for the hints.  The following will work.

HTML (appended by jQuery asynchronously):

```
<table id='dataTable'>
    <tr>
        <td class='td1'>a</td><td class='td2'>b</td><td class='td3'>c</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='td1'>1</td><td class='td2'>2</td><td class='td3'>3</td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

jQuery (call this block every time a row is appended):

```
$('tr:even td.td1').css("background-color", "#00CCCC");
$('tr:odd td.td1').css("background-color", "#00FFFF");
$('tr:even td.td2').css("background-color", "#00CC33");
$('tr:odd td.td2').css("background-color", "#00FF33");
$('tr:even td.td3').css("background-color", "#99CC33");
$('tr:odd td.td3').css("background-color", "#99FF33");
```

The drawback is that each 'TD' needs to be assigned a CSS class, and the CSS assignment is called every time a new row is appended.

Comment: I'll echo @jantimon's comment: what about `:nth-child(N)`?

Comment: I couldn't realize the power of <code>:nth-child(N)</code>
By the way, the server side would provide the entire row of data; showing the N-th set of columns would be dynamic depending on the business logic.