# Odoo - add "%" next to float field in tree view

Tags: python, odoo

How can I add "%" next to value in tree view column for below field:

rec.reserved_qty_per = round(rec.sum_reserved_qty / rec.sum_dmd_qty * 100)

when I used to add (+ "%") it's giving me an error that can't mix between float and str fields.

[image]

Here's is my Code:

```
    sum_dmd_qty = fields.Float(compute='calculate_dmd_qty', string='Total Ordered Quantity', digits=(12,0))
    sum_reserved_qty = fields.Float(compute='calculate_reserved_qty', string='Total Ready Quantity', digits=(12,0))
    reserved_qty_per = fields.Float(compute='_compute_percentage', string='Ready (%)', digits=(12,0))

    @api.depends('sum_reserved_qty', 'sum_dmd_qty')
    def _compute_percentage(self):
        for rec in self:
            if rec.sum_dmd_qty:
                rec.reserved_qty_per = round(rec.sum_reserved_qty / rec.sum_dmd_qty * 100)
```

Comment: add another field as Char field and use compute to attach %, or use jquery deal it in front end.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375625/how-to-select-a-table-column-with-jquery

Comment: Hi @TerrencePoe could you please help me with example code or Reddit on my original code I will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest one is to change `reserved_qty_per` to a `Char` field.

```py
    reserved_qty_per_chr = fields.Char(compute='_compute_percentage', string='Ready (%)')

    @api.depends('sum_reserved_qty', 'sum_dmd_qty')
    def _compute_percentage(self):
        for rec in self:
            if rec.sum_dmd_qty:
                qty = round(rec.sum_reserved_qty / rec.sum_dmd_qty * 100)
                rec.reserved_qty_per = "{0} {1}".format(qty,"%")
```

Comment: dear @Terrence, could you please help how can I add this field to sale order tree view as it is for now I added it to picking tree view

Comment: You have to add `,store=true` then, add another related field in sale order link to it. You can see [this](https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/question/how-to-use-related-field-in-odoo-11-135643).

Comment: thank you, but what is the replacement to "partner_id" in your example please?

Comment: In short, you can get info from m2o field. For example, sale order has a m2o field `product_id` and you can get product price through related attr `price = field.float(related='product_id.price')`. the name and the type of the field must be the same.