# Check, unckeck checkbox in each row of table based on Checkbox ID using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox, html-table

I am trying to check, Uncheck checkbox based on id.
I have two column in table.

```
    *current  paper * arrear paper
```

if one paper is selected in current that paper should be disabled from arrear paper
and if is selected in arrear column that particular paper should be disabled from current paper.

My Problem is that i am able to disable the **Arrear Paper** if that specific paper is selected in current column, but if i uncheck that selected paper in current column, it does not enable that paper in arrear column.
This same problem is in `SelectAll` Checkbox function also
if i click `SelectAll` in P1 paper,Current Column i want to disable that column in P1 **Arrear Paper** Column

Can Anyone Please Guide Me to Overcome this issue.
Thanks in Advance

MY FIDDLE :  [Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/n2ksoqge/)

**Snippet :**

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    var el = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      var dis = 'A-' + $(this).attr("id");
      var value = $(this).closest('tr').find('#' + dis);
      value.prop('disabled', true);
    }
  })
});
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    //  var el = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
    if ($(this).is(":not(:checked)")) {
      var dis = 'A-' + $(this).attr("id");
      var value = $(this).closest('tr').find('#' + dis);
      value.prop('disabled', false);
    }
  })
});

function SelectAll(obj) {
  // find the index of column
  var table = $(obj).closest('table');
  var th_s = table.find('th');
  var current_th = $(obj).closest('th');
  var columnIndex = th_s.index(current_th) - 1;

  console.log('The Column is = ' + columnIndex);

  // select all checkboxes from the same column index
  table.find('td:nth-child(' + (columnIndex) + ') input').prop("checked", obj.checked).change();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table style="width:100%;" id="mytable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th style="padding:2.5px;" colspan="3" style="text-align:center;">Current Paper</th>
    <th style="padding:2.5px;" colspan="3">Arrear Paper</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>P1<br/> <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" onclick="SelectAll(this)" /></th>
    <th>P2 <br/><input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" onclick="SelectAll(this)" /></th>
    <th>P3 <br/><input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" onclick="SelectAll(this)" /></th>
    <th>P1<br/> <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" onclick="SelectAll(this)" /></th>
    <th>P2 <br/><input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" onclick="SelectAll(this)" /></th>
    <th>P3<br/> <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" onclick="SelectAll(this)" /></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="P1" class="sum" value="550" data-exval="1" data-toggle="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="P2" class="sum" data-exval="1" data-toggle="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="P3" class="sum" data-exval="1" data-toggle="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input class="selectableType" type="checkbox" id=A-P1></td>
    <td><input class="selectableType" type="checkbox" id=A-P2></td>
    <td><input class="selectableType" type="checkbox" id=A-P3></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="P1" class="sum" value="550" data-exval="1" data-toggle="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="P2" class="sum" data-exval="1" data-toggle="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="P3" class="sum" data-exval="1" data-toggle="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input class="selectableType" type="checkbox" id=A-P1></td>
    <td><input class="selectableType" type="checkbox" id=A-P2></td>
    <td><input class="selectableType" type="checkbox" id=A-P3></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Basic Requirement : if a student select one particular paper in Current column that Specific Paper must be disabled from arrear column,
in a row there will be two same papers,only one shoulb be selected at a time.

Comment: you have lot of same id and its not very good..

Comment: Useless comment: The word "paper" appeared over 12 times in the question but only twice in the code!

Comment: @Frenchy  In my original code this html table is inside the loop and have multiple rows.

Comment: @Wimanicesir I tried to explain my problem clearly.

Comment: you can modify your html?

Comment: @Frenchy different id will be difficult for my other functionalities sir.

Comment: IDs must be unique in the document otherwise you'll get unexpected errors / not working code.  In *many* cases you don't need an ID at all and should either use a class or a DOM navigation.

Comment: @freedomn-m but this table will be inside the loop that execute multiple times..how is possible to use unique id

Comment: as says @freedomn-m, you can have lot of same id, but you cant use these ids to navigate in the DOM.... so in the loop use class, its better or other attributes data-something for example

Comment: With same IDs i have only this toggle checkbox  problem till now in my code.

Comment: Sanitize your html and make sure you have unique id's or no id's at all.

Comment: Is there any way to toggle checkbox without using ids ?

Comment: yes...i have a solution but need more time

Comment: ProTip:  if you want other people to look at your code, please please please, just click that [tidy] button first - it's not hard, it's provided for you, it's easy.   https://jsfiddle.net/zhbr3sjy/

Comment: @freedomn-m Sorry i dont know about that button.i will use in my next fiddle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select a table column with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375625/how-to-select-a-table-column-with-jquery)

Comment: @freedomn-m I didn't  find solution for my problem there

Comment: You asked how to select without an ID - you use the column index.   TBH your exact issue/requirement is unclear - when should the 2nd set of columns be enabled?   Should they be ticked if the first set is ticked?  If a tickbox in 2nd set is ticked, should the equivalent in the first also be clicked?

Comment: If a tickbox in 2nd set is ticked, should the equivalent in the first must be disabled (eg . if P1 is checked in 2nd column ,P1 should be disabled in 1st column and if P1 is Unchecked in 2nd,P1 should enabled in 1st column) i.e in a row there are two euivalent papers ,only one P1 should be checked at a time and other P1 should be disabled

Comment: when should the 2nd set of columns be enabled? Should they be ticked if the first set is ticked?as per my code student should select particular paper in any one column only .if he selects in current column,that specific paper in arrear column must be disbled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a little modification in your html, i have put off the onclick action and instead to use id, i use the index of each checkbox,

so main checkbox are indexed from 0 to 5,

the first line of checkbox are indexed from 6 to 11,

and the last line from 12 to 17.

I set the different values in an array and i trap the index of checkbox clicked:

```js
let sel = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
let ar = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  //if you want to add new line of checkbox ar.push([i + 6, i + 12, i + 18]);
  ar.push([i + 6, i + 12]);
}
//[[6, 12], [7, 13], [8, 14], [9, 15], [10, 16], [11, 17]]
// index for checkbox 0 is 6,12 and so on   
//console.log("checkbox", ar);

sel.change(function() {
  let lastcheckbox = sel.index($(this));
  let ischecked = sel.eq(lastcheckbox).is(":checked");
  //sel.prop("disabled", false);

  if (lastcheckbox < 6) { //main checkbox clicked
    let alt = lastcheckbox < 3 ? lastcheckbox + 3 : lastcheckbox - 3;
    ar[lastcheckbox].forEach( (item, i) => sel.eq(item).prop("checked", ischecked));

    sel.eq(alt).prop("disabled", ischecked);
    ar[alt].forEach( (item, i) => sel.eq(item).prop("disabled", ischecked));    

return;
  }

  //so its a secondary checkbox clicked
  ar.forEach((item, idx) => {
    if (item.includes(lastcheckbox)) {//find the main index of secondary checkbox
      let index = item.indexOf(lastcheckbox);
      let alt = idx < 3 ? idx + 3 : idx - 3;
      let one = item.some((idx) => sel.eq(idx).is(":checked"));
      let both = item.every((idx) => sel.eq(idx).is(":checked"));
      if (both) { //both secondary checkbox checked
        sel.eq(idx).prop("checked", true);
        sel.eq(alt).prop("disabled", true);
        ar[alt].map((i) => sel.eq(i).prop("disabled", true));
      } else if (!one && !both) { //no secondary checkbox checked
        sel.eq(idx).prop("checked", false);
        sel.eq(alt).prop("disabled", false);
        ar[alt].map((i) => sel.eq(i).prop("disabled", false));
      } else if (one && !both) {
        sel.eq(idx).prop("checked", false);
        sel.eq(alt).prop("disabled", true);
        sel.eq(lastcheckbox).prop("checked", ischecked);
        sel.eq(ar[alt][index]).prop("disabled", ischecked);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table style="width:100%;" id="mytable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th style="padding:2.5px;" colspan="3" style="text-align:center;">Current Paper</th>
    <th style="padding:2.5px;" colspan="3">Arrear Paper</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>P1<br /> <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" /></th>
    <th>P2 <br /><input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" /></th>
    <th>P3 <br /><input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" /></th>
    <th>P1<br /> <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" /></th>
    <th>P2 <br /><input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" /></th>
    <th>P3<br /> <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" /></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>


    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="P1" class="sum" value="550" data-exval="1" data-toggle="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="P2" class="sum" data-exval="1" data-toggle="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="P3" class="sum" data-exval="1" data-toggle="checkbox"></td>




    <td><input class="selectableType" type="checkbox" id=A-P1></td>
    <td><input class="selectableType" type="checkbox" id=A-P2></td>
    <td><input class="selectableType" type="checkbox" id=A-P3></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>


    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="P1" class="sum" value="550" data-exval="1" data-toggle="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="P2" class="sum" data-exval="1" data-toggle="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="P3" class="sum" data-exval="1" data-toggle="checkbox"></td>




    <td><input class="selectableType" type="checkbox" id=A-P1></td>
    <td><input class="selectableType" type="checkbox" id=A-P2></td>
    <td><input class="selectableType" type="checkbox" id=A-P3></td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank You so much  Sir.Let me Check this with my code and  Update

Comment: You have used  ar.push([i + 6, i + 12]); so it will work only for two rows ? (i.e Upto 12 index)

Comment: and what is the problem? if you want to add row, you have to adapt the program, its really easy.. do you want to add row?

Comment: Yes.This Works Perfectly.Thank You soo much for Your Help.

Answer (score 1):

You have lots of similar checkbox ids and as you have mentioned you didn't want to change them due to some reason, so the way we can do it by avoiding for loop on checkbox and calling function on checkbox change.

```
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table style="width:100%;" id="mytable" border="1">
<tr>
 <th style="padding:2.5px;" colspan="3" style="text-align:center;">Current Paper</th>
        <th style="padding:2.5px;" colspan="3">Arrear Paper</th>
     
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <th>P1<br/> <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" onclick="SelectAll(this)" /></th>
     <th>P2 <br/><input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" onclick="SelectAll(this)"/></th>
      <th>P3 <br/><input type="checkbox" id="selectAll"onclick="SelectAll(this)" /></th>
       <th>P1<br/> <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" onclick="SelectAll(this)" /></th>
     <th>P2 <br/><input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" onclick="SelectAll(this)"/></th>
      <th>P3<br/> <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll"onclick="SelectAll(this)" /></th>
    </tr>
  <tr >
    
    
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="P1" class="sum" data-type="CurrentPaper" value="550" data-exval="1" data-toggle="checkbox" onclick="checkuncheck(this);"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="P2" class="sum" 
data-exval="1" data-type="CurrentPaper" data-toggle="checkbox" onclick="checkuncheck(this);"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="P3" class="sum" 
data-exval="1" data-type="CurrentPaper" data-toggle="checkbox" onclick="checkuncheck(this);"></td>



    
     <td><input class="selectableType" type="checkbox" id="A-P1" onclick="checkuncheck(this);" data-type="ArrearPaper" ></td>
    <td><input class="selectableType" type="checkbox" id="A-P2" onclick="checkuncheck(this);" data-type="ArrearPaper" ></td>
    <td><input class="selectableType" type="checkbox" id="A-P3" onclick="checkuncheck(this);" data-type="ArrearPaper"></td>
      
    </tr>
        <tr >
    
    
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="P1" class="sum" value="550" data-type="CurrentPaper" data-exval="1" data-toggle="checkbox" onclick="checkuncheck(this);"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="P2" class="sum" 
data-exval="1" data-type="CurrentPaper" data-toggle="checkbox" onclick="checkuncheck(this);"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="P3" class="sum" 
data-exval="1" data-type="CurrentPaper" data-toggle="checkbox" onclick="checkuncheck(this);"></td>



    
     <td><input class="selectableType" type="checkbox" id="A-P1" onclick="checkuncheck(this);" data-type="ArrearPaper" ></td>
    <td><input class="selectableType" type="checkbox" id="A-P2" onclick="checkuncheck(this);" data-type="ArrearPaper" ></td>
    <td><input class="selectableType" type="checkbox" id="A-P3" onclick="checkuncheck(this);" data-type="ArrearPaper" ></td>
      
    </tr>
    </table>
    
    function checkuncheck(element){
 var dis = $(element).attr("id"); 
 if($(element).attr("data-type").toLowerCase()=="currentpaper"){
            dis='A-'+$(element).attr("id");

 }
 else{
 dis= dis.split("-")[1];
 } 
        var el = $(element).parents('tr')[0];
        
      if($(element).is(":checked")){      
           var value= $(element).closest('tr').find('#'+dis);
     value.prop('disabled', true);
       }
     else
     {
           $(element).closest('tr').find('#'+dis)
             .prop('disabled', false);
     }
}
```

you can find the code in this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/472s8cvb/

Based on the changes, try to implement select all functionlity

Comment: Thank You So much.I will try this and update